# Remove duplicates based on multiple columns and set conditions to choose one unique record

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I need SQL help in order to get rid of a duplicate in one column, based on the conditions set from other columns.

The Audit column can have NULL values. I want to prioritize the record which:

1. Gets rid of the duplicate Color
2. Then sorts by the earliest Date
3. However, if the Audit column is NULL for the earlier Date, I want to select the next record where it isn't.
4. If the Audit column is NULL for all entries, I still want the entry with the earliest Date to be selected.

Example below.

Here's what I have:

| ID | Color | Date | Audit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | red | 4-1-21 | Y |
| 2 | red | 4-2-21 | N |
| 3 | blue | 4-3-21 |  |
| 4 | blue | 4-4-21 | Y |
| 5 | pink | 4-5-21 |  |
| 6 | pink | 4-6-21 |  |

Here's what I want:

| ID | Color | Date | Audit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | red | 4-1-21 | Y |
| 4 | blue | 4-4-21 | Y |
| 5 | pink | 4-5-21 |  |

Can anyone help me figure out the SQL logic to properly execute this?

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that your want to choose the yes audit record, if available, followed by no, then followed by `NULL`, if neither of the previous two be available.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (Color) *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY Color, Audit DESC NULLS LAST, Date;
```